# F4 Visa Aged out 25 year old

Tags: visa, immigration, family, greencard

My uncle filed for the f4 visa in 2007 for my father(beneficiary). The priority date is April 4th, 2007. At the time of the filing and priority date I was 12 years old at the time. The petition was approved on March 15th, 2012 and at that time I was 17 years old. As of right now am 25 years old (2019) and the priority date for April 2007 is just around the corner based on the current visa bulletin for October 2019. Also when I login to CEAC, I only see my parents names. I know am just a derivative and not the primary applicant, but here are the dates.

Filed: April 4th, 2007 Priority 
 Approved: March 15, 2012

I just want to know if CSPA applies to me and will I be able to attain, or eligible for, a visa since am 25 right now?

Answer (score 1):

The I-130 petition was pending for just under 5 years, so you should not age out until just before age 26 (21 + length of time the petition was pending). You say you are 25 years old, but without the exact birthdate it is impossible to tell whether you have aged out or when you will age out. If at the time a visa number becomes available for the priority date, you haven't aged out, you can immigrate as as derivative beneficiary if you seek to acquire a visa within one year of it becoming available.

Comment: August 27, 1994

Comment: @user19106: then I believe you do not age out as long as a visa number becomes available by August 2020, and it does not later retrogress